# VBA: Run time error '91'?

Tags: vba

All I'm trying to do here is save a reference to the currently active window, but it doesn't seem to be working.  It gives me a run time error on the last line.

```
Dim SourceWindow As Window, QACheckWindow As Window
SourceWindow = ActiveWindow
```

I'm not exactly sure why.  Isn't `ActiveWindow` supposed to return the currently active window?  If not, how can I make a reference to it?

EDIT: The above is right at the beginning of my function, so all there is before it is `Sub FuncName()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Set SourceWindow = ActiveWindow`?

Comment: Aha! Yeah, I don't use VB much as it seems to show.  Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In VB object variables require the `Set` keyword to be assigned. Object properties that are objects also need to be `Set`. Runtime error 91 "object variable not set" is raised when the assignment doesn't use that keyword.

This is inherited from legacy `Let` keyword to assign *values*, and `Set` keyword to assign *references*; the `Let` eventually was deprecated (although still needed for defining properties) and the `Set` remained, leaving the VB6/VBA value assignment syntax like `[Let] variable = value`, where "Let" is optional.

In the declaration and assignment:

```
Dim SourceWindow As Window, QACheckWindow As Window
'this is like saying "Let SourceWindow = ActiveWindow":
SourceWindow = ActiveWindow
```

`SourceWindow` is an *object*, assigned as if it were a *value* - this causes VBA to attempt *let-coercion* through a *default member call*. If the object wasn't initialized, the member call fails with error 91. If the object was initialized but doesn't have a *default member*, error 438 is raised.

So in this case error 91 is being raised because of an implicit member call; the .net equivalent would be a `NullReferenceException`:

```
Dim SourceWindow As Window, Dim WindowTitle As String
'"SourceWindow" reference isn't set, the object can't be accessed yet:
WindowTitle = SourceWindow.Caption
```

---

I'm going to go a bit overboard here, but the legacy `Let` *statement* should not be confused with the `Let` *clause* (in VB.net) which, in the LINQ *query syntax* (in VB.net), computes a value and assigns it to a new, query-scoped variable (example taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531379.aspx)):

```
From p In products 
Let Discount = p.UnitPrice*0.1 '"Discount" is only available within the query!
Where Discount >= 50
Select p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice, Discount
```

VB.net assigns both *values* and *references*, without the need to specify a `Let` or a `Set`, because in .net this distinction is a much thinner line, given how everything ultimately derives from `System.Object`... including `System.ValueType`. That's why [the `Set` keyword was also deprecated in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468890/what-did-vb-replace-the-function-set-with), and also why the VB.net syntax for defining properties has dropped the `Let` in favor of `Set` - because parameterless *default members* are illegal in VB.NET, so this ambiguous *let-coercion* doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks.  Coming from other languages, `Set` seems a little superfluously verbose.

Comment: Although pointing out the error in the code here, this answer is not fully correct. Error 91 is exactly the equivalent of a NullReferenceException. Whether you get error 91 or error 438 (member not supported) for a Let assignment on an object (without default member) depends on whether the object is initialized already. VBA will try to access a default member to get a value. If the variable is initialized and does not have a default member, you get error 438. If is is not initialized, you get error 91, because you tried to access a default member on Nothing.