# RTE 91 vs CTE Object Required: Fixing One Causes the Other?

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Function printerpart(outputtext As Collection) As Collection
    Dim TotalRecords As Integer 'Original build didn't include this line; no other declaration of TotalRecords, though?
    Set TotalRecords = outputtext.Count
    For i = 1 To TotalRecords
        outputext = outputtext(i)
        outputext = Replace(outputext, "&", "and")
        Print #1, outputext
    Next i
    Set printerpart = New Collection
End Function
```

When attempting to run this function, an error occurs on the line assigning a value/object to TotalRecords. Initial builds did not include the `Set` statement on that line, but failing to include it results in RTE 91. With `Set`, however, the function encounters a compile-time error: Object Required.

Each call to `printerpart` passes `outputtext` as a collection of string objects.

I am aware of how terrible the variable names are and intend to fix them.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927297/) seems to imply that the `Set` statement should only be used to assign Object variables, and that lacking it is the cause of RTE 91 in most cases. Does declaring TotalRecords as an Integer make it an object? The same errors occur if TotalRecords is not declared until its assignment statement.

What is the proper method for resolving these errors in this context, given that the commonly suggested fix for one issue causes the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove the "set" the error you get is not according to TotalRecords, it refers to outputtext, seems like what you are passing to function does not have the .count property, check again the variable passed to the function please

Comment: Collections do have the `.count` property so `outputtext` must be `Nothing`

Comment: After enclosing the function contents in `If (Not outputtext Is Nothing Then`, the same error occurs, so I believe we can rule out outputtext being `Nothing`; unless I'm misunderstanding that conditional, of course.

Comment: and did you remove the "set" before "totalrecords?"

Comment: Doh! Well, that part of the method runs cleanly now, at least. There are still errors, but I'm not sure whether they merit a fresh post; should I open a new question for another RTE 91 in a different part of the file? It's showing up on a call to Collection.Add now.

Comment: think you should:) it might get confusing for discussion new joiners