# Compile Error: BC30807: Assignment statements 'Let' and 'Set' are not supported

Tags: html, asp.net, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I am trying to make a connection to an access database (Version 2003) from an html (Generated in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008), but when executing it I get the error BC30807: The assignment statements 'Let' and 'Set' are not compatible. Because it can be?

I leave the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">

    <link type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <title>Conexion Access</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <%
        set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        conn.Open(Server.Mappath("/bd/coches.mdb"))
        set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
        rs.Open "Select * from coches", conn
        
        rs.close
        conn.close
        
    %>


    <div id="mapid"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapa.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: @शेखर - no, that is about "set as *startup project*", not the `Set` keyword as used here

Comment: But maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468890/what-did-vb-replace-the-function-set-with (ASP.Net uses VB.Net (or C#), not VB)

Comment: And searching for that error code leads to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30807)

Comment: sorry my bad pasted a wrong link.